# Android Studio error in Environment.java cannot resolve symbol com.google.android

Tags: java, android

I downloaded and install Java Version 8 JDK.
Android Studio is at latest update.
My build.gradle file has:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
```

The android manifest has:
    uses-adk android:minSdkVersion="9"
It also has: 
    "android:targetSdkVersion="10""
In the Environment.java, the: import com.google.android.collect.Lists;
shows "android" in red with cannot resolve symbol 'android'.
Should I, perhaps, uninstall Java JDK 8 and re-install Java JDK 7?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio currently supports only java 6 and 7. Try to use java 7. See [android studio installation specs](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html).

For java 7 use compile options in your gradle project.

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```